# How to parse templated container class as a type

Tags: c++

I have to make this program where I log a users random browsing history for a "pool" of users. I am nearly finished but I cant seem to find the problem with the line in the main method "Pool p1()".

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Users{

    private:
        //static constexpr int numUsers = 5;
        T numWebsites;
        vector<T> browsingHistory;

    public:
        Users(int nw);
        void UrlGeneration();
        vector<T> getBrowsingHistory();
        int calculateMinVariety();
        int calculateMinDifference();
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Users<T> &);
};

template <typename T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Users<T> &u) {
    typename vector<T>::iterator i;
    for(i = u.getBrowsingHistory(); i != u.getBrowsingHistory().end(); i++){
        out << *i << " ";
    }
    return out;
}

template <typename T>
Users<T>::Users(int nw){
    numWebsites = nw;
}

template <typename T>
void Users<T>::UrlGeneration(){

    unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    std::default_random_engine randEng(seed);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<T> distribution(0, numWebsites);

    //Create a number of websites - digits 1  to 10.
    //Create values
    for(int i = 0; i < numWebsites; i++){
        int randNum = distribution(randEng);
        //Append them to the array for this user
        browsingHistory.push_back(randNum);
    }
}

template<typename T>
vector<T> Users<T>::getBrowsingHistory(){
    return browsingHistory;
}

template <typename V>
class Pool{

    private:
        vector<V> users;

    public:
        void display();
        void addUsers(V u);

        Pool();
};

template <typename V>
Pool<V>::Pool(){
}

template <typename V>
void Pool<V>::display(){
    for(V u: users){
        cout << u;
    }
}

template <typename V>
void Pool<V>::addUsers(V u){
    users.push_back(u);
}
       
int main(){

    Users<int> u1(10);
    u1.UrlGeneration();
    Pool<Users> p1();
    p1.addUsers(u1);
    p1.display();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should simplify the code in your question. Do you retain the error if you eliminate the `Users<int> u1(10);` and `u1.UrlGeneration();` lines? If so, eliminate them.  (I suppose `p1.addUsers(u1);` would also need to be eliminated as it uses `u1`, but you might need to keep `p1.display();` so that you attempt to use `p1`.) Keep simplifying. Get rid of all the functions you do not need to use. Can you get the definition of `Users` down to `template <typename T>
class Users{};` while still retaining your current error?

Comment: Also, you should copy the text of your error message into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Per the ["Most Vexing Parse"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse), if something looks like a function declaration, it is treated as a function declaration.

`Pool<Users> p1();` is not a variable declaration, like you are expecting.  It is a function declaration.  It is declaring a function `p1` that takes no arguments and returns a `Pool<Users>`.

What you want is a variable named `p1` of type `Pool<Users>` instead.  You need to drop the parenthesis `()` to get that, eg:

```cpp
Pool<Users> p1;
```

Or, you can use curly braces `{}` instead:

```cpp
Pool<Users> p1{};
```

Never use empty parenthesis `()` to invoke a type's *default* constructor.

That being said, `Users` is also a template, so you need to provide a type for its `T` template argument, ie:

```cpp
Pool<Users<int>> p1;
```

Comment: I have removed the default constructor however I am still getting a type mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list error. The compiler is complaining about the Pool<Users> line